# Why would there be any static resources in a Spring Boot backend that serves an Angular frontend?

Tags: angular, spring-security

I am following [this](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/) tutorial to try and understand how to implement the Login form for an Angular app with a Spring Boot backend.

I have read until 'Handling the Login Request on the Server'. In this section, it is stated that the security configuration should permit access to the server's static resources:

`.antMatchers("/index.html", "/", "/home", "/login").permitAll()`

However, I don't understand why there would be any static resources on my server: The HTML and CSS and JS files are all part of my frontend, which - at least that's my understanding - is being hosted using node.js on localhost:4200. My backend implements a REST API to serve information coming from a database to my frontend. The backend is using Spring Boot and is hosted on localhost:8080. My backend does not contain any HTML, CSS or JS files.

When my frontend is sending a REST call to my backend, Spring Security filters this request. I won't be requesting the `index.html` page or so, however, but a resource coming from a database. I can only imagine this is somehow related to how the frontend and the backend will be packaged and deployed later - I have never done that before and, therefore, don't know how things come into play.

Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: I think, and i'm *not* sure here, but I think they are referring to Spring simply having anonymous access to the static resources on the client. Perhaps a bit of bad wording. It appears Spring needs access to any page, login/home/index.html since the users can be logged in or even logged out.

Comment: "The last thing we need to remember is to make the JavaScript components provided by Angular available anonymously to the application. We could do that in the HttpSecurity configuration above, but since it is static content, it’s better to simply ignore it"

Comment: i looked at the tutorial and sadly it is quite old, here is the gitrepo for the project https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js its using spring 1.5.6 and today current as of writing version is 2.7.2 so the tutorial is about 5 years old. There are several PRs that want to upgrade the the project but it hasn't been merged yet

Comment: allright, thx so much for your help, guys! I didn't realize the Tutorial was old. Do you by any chance know of a good up-to-date Tutorial that i could follow? Cause I have been looking around the internet and I feel like there is loads of information, but a lot of differences as well and i cannot tell apart which would be the best way to implement login nowadays.